# How do I dynamiclly define this button?

Tags: c#, xaml

How do I define this in C# code so it is created at runtime?

```
<Button Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="380" Content="Answer" Height="23" Name="submit_btn" Width="75" Click="submit_btn_Click" />
```

Comment: This is the second time you've done this, what have you learned from the first time you posted a question like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var b = new Button { Text = "Hello World", Left = 100, Top = 100, Width = 50, Height = 25 };
Controls.Add(b);
```

Place in constructor after InitializeComponent().